# pandas how to sort groupby by group sizes while aggregating on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
id    amount
1     20
2     8
1     3
1     2
2     7
```

I want to `groupby` the `df` by `id`, and sorting the groups by their sizes,

```
 df.groupby('id').size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

but also aggregate on `amount` of each group to create a separate column `total` at the same time,

```
id    amount    total    size
1     20         25       3
1     3          25       3
1     2          25       3
2     8          15       2
2     7          15       2
```

Comment: why do you have `(ascending=False)` when you actually sorted it in ascending order in the example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `agg` with a list, followed by `pd.merge`:

```
g = df.groupby('id')['amount'].agg(['size', 'sum'])

res = pd.merge(df, g, left_on='id', right_index=True)\
        .sort_values('size', ascending=False)

print(res)

   id  amount  size  sum
0   1      20     3   25
2   1       3     3   25
3   1       2     3   25
1   2       8     2   15
4   2       7     2   15
```